# launch a function only when data received from Ethernet device in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, ethernet

I'm writing a vb.net application, to receive data from Ethernet device and store that data in a text file. Is there any way to launch a function only when data is sent from the device??

For eg,

```
Public Sub Main()
      'This should run only when data is received from the device
end sub
```

here is my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
'Data buffer for incoming data.
Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
Dim remoteEP As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("169.254.244.11"), 10051)

'Create a TCP/IP socket.
Dim sender As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, _
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
Public Sub Main()
    'Connect the socket to the remote endpoint.
    sender.Connect(remoteEP)

    Dim bytesRec2, time_date

    time_date = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")

    Dim filepath As String = "hexfiles/" & time_date + ".hex"


    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
    End If

    Dim text_data

    While (True)

        bytesRec2 = sender.Receive(bytes)

        text_data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec2)

        ByteArrayToFile(filepath, GetByteArray(bytes, 0, bytesRec2))

        If text_data.IndexOf("CALL END") >= 0 Then

            Dim newFilePath As String = filepath.Replace(".hex", ".mp3")

            System.IO.File.Move(filepath, newFilePath)
            sender.Disconnect(1)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End While

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call Main()
End Sub

Private Function GetFileContents(ByVal file_name As String) As String
    Dim stream_reader As New IO.StreamReader(file_name)
    Dim txt As String = stream_reader.ReadToEnd()
    stream_reader.Close()
    Return txt
End Function

Private Function GetByteArray(ByVal MyArray As System.Array, ByVal Start As Integer, ByVal Length As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim ReturnValue(Length - 1) As Byte
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(MyArray, Start, ReturnValue, 0, Length)
    Return ReturnValue
End Function

Public Function ByteArrayToFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _ByteArray() As Byte) As Boolean

    Try
        ' Open file for reading
        Dim _FileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)

        ' Writes a block of bytes to this stream using data from a byte array.
        _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, _ByteArray.Length)

        ' close file stream
        _FileStream.Close()

        Return True
    Catch _Exception As Exception
        ' Error
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString())
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: In what format does the data come? TCP or some more raw protocol?

Comment: please go through my updated question.